# traverse button from span to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newly learning jQuery and java script,currently i am  facing a problem in showing the hidden button,my html is

```
<span style="float:left;padding-right:10px">
    <input type="button" value="image" class="delete" />
    <a href="/media/image"><img src="/media/image" /></a>
</span>
<span style="float: left; padding-top: 5px;">
    <a href="/media/image">
        <button  type="submit" class="delete_media">Delete</button>
    </a>
</span>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){         
 var $this = $(this);   
 $this.siblings(".delete_media").toggle();             
});
```

css:

```
.delete_media {    
    display:none;
    float: right;
    height: 25px;
    width: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius:10px;    
}
```

Also i tried using find,nextAll,closest also nothing worked so how to make this work.

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/jF86x/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $this.closest('span').next().find(".delete_media").toggle();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2zGQ/)

Comment: This is really coupled with the current DOM.

Comment: @user2725407 It'll stop working the moment you'll slightly change your DOM. Lets say you'll add an image between these two spans, this solution will stop working

Answer (score 1):

You're using siblings but they're not on the same container. Other traversing function won't do the job as well because those two buttons doesn't have a common container.

Just search it by class

```
$(".delete").click(function(){         
   var $this = $(this);   
   $(".delete_media").toggle();             
});
```

It's advisable that you'll wrap those two buttons with a common container.

Here's an  example

```
<div data-action="delete">
    <span style="float:left;padding-right:10px">
        <input type="button" value="image" class="delete" />
        <a href="/media/image"><img src="/media/image" /></a>
    </span>
    <span style="float: left; padding-top: 5px;">
        <a href="/media/image">
            <button  type="submit" class="delete_media">Delete</button>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>

$(".delete").click(function(){         
   var $this = $(this);   
   $this.closest("div[data-action='delete']")
                          .find(".delete_media").toggle();             
});
```

Comment: This will fail if the OP has multiple of those elements and wants to toggle only the one that is related to the delete button. You also don't use this line `var $this = $(this);`.

Comment: There's no common container... Other solutions with .parent() and .next() etc would be really coupled with the DOM

Comment: @user2725407 So put them on a common container. See my update